# scroll to top not animating smoothly

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrolltop

My code:

```
$('#scroll-image').click(function(){
    $(window).animate({scrollTop: 0}, 2000);
    return false;
});
```

When i click on #scroll-image the page does scroll up but it happens instantly. I want it to scroll smoothly. I looked around and other's use the same code and theirs works perfectly. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: "0" }, 2000);
```

As in:

```js
$('#scroll-image').on('click', function(){
                $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 2000);
                return false;
        });
```

```css
.box {
  
height: 1000px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>

<a id="scroll-image" href="#">Scroll to top</a>
```

The reason you animate `html` AND `body` is because different browsers respond to different elements -- by doing both it will be compatible with more browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You want to animate the **html** and **body** elements, not the window.

```
$('#scroll-image').click(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 2000);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You're getting errors using `$(window)`. Use `$("html, body")` instead.

```
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 2000);
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oyaka312/2/).